# How to Refresh gridview contents

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a two gridviews, gridview1 and gridview2.

I want to refresh gridview2 on `MouseClick` event of gridview1. When I click on gridview1, gridview2 loads with data based on the primary key. For example, if I select first row (id 1) in gridview1, then the corresponding data loads in a gridview2, but if I select row two (id 2) then gridview2 loads with id 2 data and removes id 1 data.

Here is the code I have so far, but didn't work. It loads data into gridview2 as many times as many times I select a row in gridview1. Please help.

```
private void gridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SendValues();
        gridView2.DataSource = null;
        gridView2.Rows.Clear();
        gridView2.Columns.Clear();
        gridView2.Refresh();

        posting_log();
    }
```

Comment: winforms or web forms ?

Comment: @mybirthname winforms bro

Comment: Did you try gridView2.Update();

Comment: Yeah i did that also but it still loads multiple data of selected row

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa! Also tag Winforms!!

Comment: Do the tables have relations? DO you have a typed dataset and table adapters?